# Remove period at the end of subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, punctuation, amsart

I am using amsart.  For specific isolated uses of subsubsection*, I would like to prevent the addition of a period at the end of the title.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Don't fence me in}  Some text.

\subsubsection*{Or at least let me use pictures like} {\it \hspace{-.3cm} 
$\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\draw[double] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}$ inside a title.}
Some more text.

\subsubsection*{Fine go ahead}  And a bit more.

\end{document}
```

In this example, in the second use of \subsubsection*, I would like to remove the period after `like'.  As you can see, my real motivation is to be able to use tikz in a subsubsection heading, but in my circumstance, it seems the easiest workaround would just be to remove the period and fake the second half of the section title, as above.

Comment: try adding `\nopunct` at the end of that title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the ams document classes provide the command `\nopunct` to omit the automatically added period at the end of (sub)section headings.

the rationale is that a heading might reasonably end with a question mark or similar, so no additional punctuation is wanted.  since tex doesn't process backwards, this has to be specified manually.

Comment: Barbara Beeton's comment does the trick: \nopunct.

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Notice however that the \nopunct produces some trailing garbage "1007" in the PDF table of contents bookmarks of that section. (I'm still using a 2022 latex installation.)

Comment: @OskarLimka -- I've never heard of that problem.  I think it's worth a new question of its own.  Please provide a small compilable example that triggers the problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I will try to update TeX instal first and if problem persists, I'll share it as a question.