# Remove period at the end of section numbers in amsart

Tags: sectioning, amsart

For instance, `amsart` formats a subsection number as `1.2.` but I want `1.2`, as in the standard `article` class.

[These](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500807/how-to-remove-dot-from-subsection-in-appendix) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142167/remove-period-at-the-end-of-subsubsection) ask how to remove the period following the *heading* (`\nopunct`), but I have been unable to find anything on removing the period after the number.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{$\leftarrow$ I'd like to remove this period}

\subsection{$\leftarrow$ And this one too}

\subsubsection{$\leftarrow$ This one as well}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \protect\textup{\protect\@secnumfont
    \csname the#1\endcsname
%%%    \protect\@secnumpunct
\space
  }%
}


\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1 #2%.
     \quad}}#3}
\let\tocsubsection\tocsection
\let\tocsubsubsection\tocsection

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{$\leftarrow$ I'd like to remove this period}

\subsection{$\leftarrow$ And this one too}

\subsubsection{$\leftarrow$ This one as well}

\end{document}
```